# ghostscript BoundingBox values

Tags: ghostscript

I'm just asking myself, what are those bbox values printed out by:

```
gs -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=bbox myfile.pdf

%%BoundingBox: 46 911 1668 4537
%%HiResBoundingBox: 46.080002 911.520035 1667.520064 4536.000173
```

top-left-X, top-left-Y, ....?

And what's the measurement of those values (1/72")?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These values are given in PostScript "points":

```
72 points == 1 inch
```

so yes, the measurement value is 1/72''...

The four values need to be read as two pairs of coordinates describing the lower left and the upper right corner points of a rectangle enclosing the bounding box.

The PostScript coordinate system has its origin in the lower left corner.

The `46 911` part is for the lower left corner point: 46 *points* distance from the <strike>right</strike> left edge and 911 *points* from the bottom edge.

The `1668 4537` part is for the upper right corner point: 1668 *points* distance from the <strike>right</strike> left edge and 4537 *points* from the bottom edge.

---

(Corrected a somewhat legasthenic error... Thanks to Scolytus for spotting it.)

Comment: @pipitas: There seems to be some typos in the answer. Since I don't know what's correct I can't suggest an edit. You write for both coordinate pairs that they describe the lower left corner point. Can you please also clarify what the coordinate origin is? If it's in the lower left corner, why are the distances measured from the right edge? thx

Comment: @Scolytus: thanks for the hint. You are right. There are/were typos. I'll correct them now.