# PDF: split pages containing more than one presentation slide per page

Tags: pdf, scripting, ghostscript

Course material often contains more than one slide per PDF-page. I'd like to write a command line script that splits those pages up so that each page of the PDF contains just one slide. I've seen a lot of different arrangements of the slides on a page, but within a single PDF it's always the same, so a per PDF configuration of the cutting geometry should be sufficient.

Which free libraries or tools offer this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these answers at superuser.com:

- [Linux-based tool to chop PDFs into multiple pages](https://superuser.com/a/192293/40894)
- [Freeware to split a pdf's pages down the middle?](https://superuser.com/a/235401/40894)

Comment: The size of a PDF-page can be obtained by the bounding box, right? Like in the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250064/ghostscript-boundingbox-values

Comment: @Scolytus: That's right. Note that the BoundingBox describes this rectangle of the page which contains any visible marks of the page image. That's different to the various PDF boxes: MediaBox, TrimBox, CropBox, ArtBox....